# Get php-fpm process information without curl

Tags: php, process

I want to get `php-fpm` information (like `active processes`) without doing the `curl http://domain/status` request.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could execute on shell....

```
exec('/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm status');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php